# jBPM/Seam Recipes?

Tags: java, jboss, seam, jbpm, recipe

I'd like to learn a bit more about jBPM and how I can leverage it within my JBoss Seam-based application.  I've taken a look at the documentation, and written a couple of basic test applications to get comfortable with it, however I'd like to learn a bit more about best practices and real-world scenarios using jBPM.  Does anyone know of any good resources for finding "jBPM recipes" or real-world examples?  Things like a user registration system for a website, trouble ticketing, eCommerce order processing, etc.  I'd like to see how other people are structuring their business processes to get a sense of what to do (and what not to do) when using jBPM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the DVD Store example application in the seam bundle. That uses jBPM. You can also find other jbpm projects in the example folder in seam.